# Central administration service stopped

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration

I stopped the central administration from the Application server, and now I can't configure anything on SharePoint.

Is there a way to restart it again? I have only one application server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start Central administration service instance via Sharepoint Management PowerShell as the following

- Open SharePoint PowerShell as administrator
- Run the following cmdlet `Get-SPServiceInstance`

[image]

- The `central administration` will be listed > Mark its GUID that surrounded by orange.
- Put it in the following cmdlet `Start-SPServiceInstance -Identity <ServiceGUID>` to be like this `Start-SPServiceInstance -Identity 12ab21be-868a-41d1-ba46-3dffe09d82c1`
- Now the central administration should be started and navigated.